# user types in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

in my web application a user belongs to a client or a company.
I try to implement that so:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey('client.Client', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company = models.ForeignKey('company.Company', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin

    @property
    def is_company(self):
        if self.company:
            return True

        return False

    @property
    def is_client(self):
        if self.company:
            return True

        return False

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.client and self.company:
            raise ValidationError("Test")

        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I need these differentiation because a company can maintained multiple clients and a client and a company can have multiple users.

But is that the best way to implement this? I have read that i can't create multiple user classes in django, so i must implement this functionality in only one user class..

Answer (score 0):

Your code imo looks quite allright is kinda matches the best (imo) tutorial on how to create roles using django from here: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html
On the other hand you can actually make everything by yourself by creating separate models and and authorization - Thats a lot of work but you'll have everything under control.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this is not a good approach effectively. One should not alterate the `User` base structure, and code things such as `is_admin` and so on.

One way to go would be the following:

- create a profile model for any type of user you will have: `RegularProfile`, `CompanyProfile`, etc. Those profiles will have a `User` attribute (`OneToOneField`).
- those profiles can inheritate a `mixin` profile for common attributes (`address`, `profile_picture`...).
- each profile will then have attributes and method belonging only to it: `company_contract`, `birth_date` for regular user, and so on.
- you will then create groups for those users, never mind if only one type of profile belongs to one group. No need to read any blog, `Django` [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) is very good for that, that's what I've read first time I needed groups and permissions.
- after that, you check for each view if connected user belongs to the right group so he can access the view. You did almost all the work when you tried to override `has_perm` method: don't stop here, and use all functionalities coming with groups and permissions! **DRY** (Don't Repeat Yourself).

To me, this way to work is the cleanest I know:

- you don't mix stuff related to regular users and stuff related to companies, so it is much easier to maintain,
- still, you can have common stuff for both of them (use mixin classes to inheritate from for instance),
- you can clearly limit the rights of each group to access one view or another,
- and I had the exact same problematic as yours, and I am very happy with that way to work (if you actually needed a feedback :-) ).

Comment: Thanks but how can i check the profile in a view or so? I have read [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@sowmendipta/creating-multiple-user-types-and-implementing-login-signup-with-email-instead-of-username-in-django-63a47be0e1af) and they use one model for multiple "profiles" but how can i do this with multiple models?

Comment: Your question is how can you access the profile? If you give a `related_name` value to your `OneToOneField`, you will be able to access that profile with `my_user.regular_profile` or `my_user.company_profile`. You can check the permission of the user, and execute according code (just with a "if... else..." statement). You can also access profiles in the templates, that's the same also! You can check user permission, and access the appropriate profile :-)

Comment: For the views, one thing I often do is to have specific view for such group or another. In that view, I use the `PermissionRequiredMixin` (same as `LoginRequiredMixin`), and override the `has_permission` method. But this is not mandatory, you can have only one view to run them all!